Error al guardar un archivo php en Wordpress
Tengo un sitio web de gestión y creación de ligas deportivas hecho con Wordpress. He creado un nuevo archivo PHP dentro de mi tema activo que lo que hace es listar las ligas que tiene actualmente ese club y se le pide un email. La idea es que se mande un código por correo electrónico al email introducido, para poder apuntarse a la liga seleccionada. Cada liga ejerce como un botón de envío de formulario. Todo esto hecho con HTML/CSS, PHP y Javascript.
Pues bien, el problema viene que al darle a "Actualizar archivo", dentro del editor de temas de Wordpress, la primera vez me lo guarda correctamente. Pero a partir de la segunda me salta el error "Algo ha ido mal. Tu cambio no se ha podido guardar. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo. También es posible que tengas que corregirlo manualmente y subir el archivo por FTP."
Entiendo que si hubiera un error de sintaxis no me dejaría guardar ninguna vez. He activado el modo debug en el archivo wp-config.php y no me saca nada por pantalla ni me guarda nada en el archivo de log.
Lo raro es que si me voy al explorador de archivos, veo que los cambios se guardan. Pero no es una buena práctica porque llega un momento que mi web se rompe y casi que no me funciona ninguna página y tengo que tirar de copias de seguridad.
No sé si mi código está interfiriendo en algo interno de Wordpress y hace que se rompa todo. El caso es que si comento todo el código, sigue saltándome el mismo error, a no ser que sea la primera vez.
¿Alguien sabe qué puede estar pasando?

Hola. Faltan detalles en tu pregunta. ¿Podrías mostrar qué instrucciones has puesto para activar el modo debug en wp-config.php? Hay varias opciones de debug que actúan de distintos modos según lo que hayas puesto. Sea como sea, convendría que revises también el log de errores, donde encontrarás con toda seguridad información valiosa del fallo. Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.

Ya está solucionado. El problema era que estaba metiendo directamente en ese archivo php, código javascript, y dentro de Wordpress hay que tratarlo de diferente manera. No le hace gracia que se meta así tal cual en un archivo php

No es cuestión de hacerle gracia, sino de seguridad. Bueno, a nadie le hace gracia que le hackeen el sitio :) Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto, pero esta área es sólo para respuestas. Si quieres aportar una respuesta debes indicar cómo lo has resuelto, poniendo el código, de modo que la pregunta pueda servir a futuros usuarios. Saludos.
